# How to edit .eml file generated with email.generator in Outlook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime

I have a code, that generate me .eml message file which I open in Outlook. But the message file is uneditable (can't edit this file). E.g.: I want to add new sender or recepiant, but I can't do that.

Does anybody know, how fix this problem, or may be there is another way to create message file?

```py
import email
from email import generator
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.encoders import encode_base64
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import json
import SQL_from_DB
import os
import re

def create_mail(attach_file_name, message_json, mail_template_path, save_path, database, db_username, db_password, driver):
    file_name_mail_template = mail_template_path + re.sub("QWE:\[.*?\]\s+","",message_json['message']) + '.txt'

    try:
        mail_template_file = open(file_name_mail_template.encode('utf-8'), 'r', encoding="utf-8")
    except:
        print("Ошибка открытия шаблона пиьсма \"" + re.sub("QWE:\[.*?\]\s+","",message_json['message']) + ".txt\"")
        sys.exit()

    mail_template_text = mail_template_file.read()
    for var, value in message_json.items():
        mail_template_text = mail_template_text.replace('${' + str(var) + '}', str(value))
    # print(mail_template_text)
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = message_json['message']
    msg['From'] = 'qwe@qwe.qwe'
    msg['To'] = SQL_from_DB.SQL_select(database, db_username, db_password, driver, message_json['DOMAINNAME'])

    #add attachment
    attach_file = open(attach_file_name.encode('utf-8'), 'rb')
    attachment = MIMEBase("application", "msword")
    #attachment = MIMEBase("application", "pdf")
    attachment.set_payload(attach_file.read())
    attach_file.close()
    encode_base64(attachment)
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename='Events' + ".zip")
    msg.attach(attachment)
    #текст письма
    msg.attach(MIMEText(mail_template_text, 'html'))

    #save message file
    with open(save_path.encode("utf-8"), 'w') as out:
        gen = email.generator.Generator(out)
        gen.flatten(msg)
        return(save_path)
```

Comment: do you have this problem with .eml files from other source ? It can be problem with Outlook, not with .eml or code. In Thunderbird you can't edit existing emails - except emails im folder "Drafts". To edit other email you have option "Edit as new mail" (right click on mail and it shows menu with this option).

Comment: Oh! Thanks, @furas. You gave me idea. Problem has been solved)

Answer (score 2):

To generate an editable Outlook file, just need generate not .eml but .emltpl (Outlook message template file).

```
#save message file
    with open('/save_path/message.emltpl', 'w') as out:
        gen = email.generator.Generator(out)
        gen.flatten(msg)
        return(save_path)
```